# Using :last-child with class selector

Tags: css

I want to style the last/second `.heading`.

```
<ul>
    <li class="heading">Hello world</li>
    <li>Hello world</li>
    <li>Hello world</li>
    <li class="heading">Hello world</li>
    <li>Hello world</li>
</ul>
```

Neither

```
ul li.heading:last-child {
    background: black;
}
```

nor

```
ul li.heading:nth-child(2) {
    background: black;
}
```

works for me. Why, and how can I apply styles to that `<li>`? It seems pseudo-class selectors doesn't work with class selectors. Which is weird since I could've sworn I'd used it before.

**Update:** Oops, totally forgot [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Znarkus/7maSx/).

Comment: I don't believe there is a way you can select the child of a class with these pseudo-class selectors. Is it always the 4th heading in a list or is it always the 2nd instance of class .heading that you want to style? If always 4th the below answer should work fine although you could also use nth-of-type.

Comment: You make your own life difficult if you don't fix this problem at the markup/semantic/html level. Using nested `ul`s will allow you to do exactly what you want with CSS2 selectors.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your statement was: "I want to style the last/second .heading."

That would mean that you would have to write your code like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="heading">Hello world</li>
    <li class="heading">Hello world</li>
    <li class="heading">Hello world</li>
    <li class="heading">Hello world</li>
    <li class="heading">Hello world</li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul li.heading:last-child {
    background: black;
}
ul li.heading:nth-child(2) {
    background: black;
}
```

Else, with your current html-code, you would write:

```
ul li.heading:nth-child(4) {
    background: black;
}
ul li.heading:nth-child(1) {
    background: black;
}
```

I understand your thought, but the lis with the class "heading" isn't the second or last child.

Comment: I believe the asker wants to do this: style the last of the children of the `<ul>` element that have class `heading`

Answer (score 20):

you can use `ul li.heading:nth-of-type`, It will consider only heading class as per your html css will

```css
li.heading:nth-of-type(2){ background: black;}
```

or

```css
li.heading:last-of-type{ background: black;}
```

Comment: This is the actual answer to the OP's question "I want to style the last/second .heading, how can I do it". The other answers only explain why what he does doesn't work.

Comment: This does not work either. These select the 2nd or last li element, ONLY IF it ALSO has the .heading class. It does not just select the 2nd/last li.heading element.

Comment: ... If use different tags "<span class=heading></span><div></div>", etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
ul li.heading:nth-last-child(2)
```

2 means you know how many of `<li>` are after your `<li class="heading">` in our case it is second from bottom.

Answer (score 6):

This is because `li.heading` is not the last-child nor is it the second child. It is the first and fourth child of the `ul`

Give this a try:

```
  ul li.heading:nth-child(4) {
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For modern browsers it is possible to use ['of' selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#the_of_selector_syntax) now.

```css
/* doesnt work */
.heading:last-child {
  color: blue;
}
/* doesnt work */
.heading:nth-last-child(1) {
  color: blue;
}

/* works for modern browsers */
.heading:nth-last-child(1 of .heading) {  
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <p>Content</p>
<ul>
  <li class='heading'>Adhemar da Silva</li>
  <li>Wang Junxia</li>
  <li class='heading'>Wilma Rudolph</li>
  <li>Babe Didrikson-Zaharias</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Only Firefox and Safari support this syntax at the moment, a substantial minority of browsers. So a bit premature to suggest it as an answer at this point or say 'modern' browsers.

Comment: @TylerH, if you run snippet in chrome (119.0.6045.123 in my case) you can see that its works there. So modern browseras include Safari, Firefox and latest chroms. Amd any apps packed by headless browser can use it already.