# CSS targetting the last of a class type that isn't the last-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s76J3/)

**Without altering the html** is there any way to target the last `.red` class using CSS?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="red">Red</div>
    <div class="red">Red</div>
    <div class="red">Target Me With CSS???</div>
    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
</div>
```

here's what I've tried :

```
.row > div{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}

.row .red{
    background-color:#770000;    
    color:#fff;
}

.row .red:first-child{
    background-color:#440000;    
    color:#fff;
}

/*have tried :last-of-type too*/
.row .red:last-child{
    background-color:#FF0000;    
}

.row div:last-child{
    background-color:#0000BB;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do that without using JS.

The closest you can get is to target the 3rd item with:

```
.row div:nth-child(3) {
    background: chucknorris;
}
```

You can include a qualifier to only target the third child if it is .red like so:

```
.red:nth-child(3) {  
   background: chucknorris; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s76J3/3/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do this with CSS alone. Here are a few other SO questions that are related to yours:

- [Using :last-child with class selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687597/using-last-child-with-class-selector)
- [CSS last-child selector: select last-element of specific class, not last child inside of parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i)

**However**, if your last `.red` sometimes is in different positions, and you can't change the HTML at all, then you will have to rely on some light JS/jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $('.row .red').last().addClass('last-red-class');
});
```

You can use it to add another class to the last `.red`, and just reference that in your CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/s76J3/2/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

:last-of-type description

```
The :last-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the last sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element.
```

and syntax

```
element:last-of-type { style properties }
```

So, what really going in your example is that the browser selected the right div element but it was not the last div element of its parent; therefore, nothing was applied. To test this, change all your .red class div into a span and do the following

```
.row span:last-of-type{
    background-color:#FF0000;    
}
```

then you will get a working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/s76J3/4/

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type

Comment: I specifically stated -> "Without altering the html".