# last-child for last tr with class

Tags: html, css

I need to add a bottom border to the last `<tr>` element with class `.pos` from this table:

```
<table class="table table-borderless pos-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="nowrap">Pos</th>
            <th class="nowrap">Artikelnummer</th>
            <th class="nowrap">Menge</th>
            <th class="nowrap">VK-Preis</th>
            <th class="nowrap">Rabatt %</th>
            <th class="nowrap">Preis</th>
            <th class="nowrap">Gesamt</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="pos"></tr>
        <tr class="pos"></tr>
        <tr class="pos"></tr>
        <tr class="pos"></tr>
        <tr class="pos"></tr>
        <tr class="pos"></tr>
        <tr class="pos"></tr>
        <tr class="total"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However I don't get it working with `:last-child`. I tried the following rules but none of them seems to be working:

```
.pos-table tbody tr.pos:last-child { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }
.pos-table tr.pos:last-child { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }
tr.pos:last-child { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: This appears to be something of a possible duplicate, does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687597/using-last-child-with-class-selector